# Middle Ages quaint anniversaries for March 25th?

Tags: reference-request, calendar, passover, judgement, annunciation

The following blog has a quaint list of anniversaries for the Feast of the Annunciation:

> Thus we find in some calendars of the Middle Ages the following quaint “anniversaries” listed for March 25:
>
> - The Creation of the World
> - The Fall of Adam and Eve
> - The Sacrifice of Isaac
> - The Exodus of the Jews from Egypt
> - The Incarnation
> - The Crucifixion and Death of Christ
> - The Last Judgment
>
> [Solemnity of the Annunciation, March 25](https://familyfeastandferia.com/lityear/feastdays-part-1/annunciation-march-25-2/)

I am able to associate the historical background of all these points, except the for the last point: The Last Judgement.

For example I have more or less located a source for the Sacrifice of Isaac: [Are there any Jewish or Hebrew traditions that hold that the Passover and the binding of Isaac were on the same day (15 Nisan)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94810/13061)

Thus my question: **Can someone locate a Middle Ages reference source linking The Last Judgement to the Feast of the Annunciation or the Jewish Passover of 15 Nisan?**